# iOS REST App memory optimization

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, rest, memory-management

I'm trying to make a typical infinite scroll mobile application that gets data from server via REST API and populates a table view with that data. When a user reaches the bottom cell, a new portion of data is being loaded so memory usage increases over time.

In this case, is memory consumption worth to worry about? Can an application run out of memory this way? And if so, what is the common approach to handle memory management in such applications (Twitter, Facebook app, etc)?

Maybe I should unload the most recently loaded data or something like that?

Any hints/articles/sample projects are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a typical iOS app, memory is mostly consumed by UIKit and images. You can prove that with Xcode Instruments.

So I assume this is your case.

You mentioned that you are using `UITableView`. It is well designed to conserve memory and improve scrolling performance. But it requires you to reuse the cell. You can check the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` of `UITableView`. Please refer to [iOS Developer Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html) for more details.

If you reuse the cells, the `UITableView` will allocate only several `UITableViewCell`s in whole lifecycle. When you scroll, it will automatically re-use `UITableViewCell` that are out of the visible area. So that the memory usage should be almost constant.

And about the images, you have to use cache (or object pool) so as to limit memory usage and keep scrolling performance unaffected.